# Header columns not loading/resizing in sync with body columns in jqgrid with shrinkToFit and forceFit

Tags: jqgrid, resize

The grid is loaded fine and resizing the columns also work fine (with shrinkToFit:true and forceFit:true) when the grid doesn't show the vertical scrollbar ie when not many rows are present in the grid.

But when the grid's object has more rows, vertical scroll bar appears in the grid. The grid's header columns are not in sync with body columns and resizing also continues to be out of sync between the header & body columns, even with shrinkToFit:true and forceFit:true.

From my understanding, I think the scrollbar's width is also taken into account as btable's width when the scroll bar shows which causes the out-of-sync problem.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H5IS.png)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you post JavaScript code which can be used to reproduce the problem? Do you try to remove `autowidth: true` option if you use it?

Comment: Thanks a mill, Oleg! That hint definitely led to finding the problem & hence a fix! :)

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.